# In the case of memory loss due to a blunt force impact, can memory later be restored by means of another blunt force impact?

Tags: biology, physiology, television, memory

In the case of memory loss due to a blunt force impact, can memory later be restored by means of another blunt force impact?

Seems fairly common on TV.

I did find some anecdotal evidence of this:

- [Blow on Head Restores Memory of Missing Man](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1948&dat=19310708&id=mq00AAAAIBAJ&sjid=pn8FAAAAIBAJ&pg=1242,586780)
- [Bump on Head Restores Memories of Wife, Home : After 15 Years of Amnesia, Man Returns on Christmas](http://articles.latimes.com/1985-12-28/news/mn-29577_1_returns-home)

Comment: Harry Potter is on TV too. Could magic possibly be involved?

Comment: Lol Woodchips!  Let's add the Flintstones to that list also!

Comment: tvtropes calls it [Easy Amnesia](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EasyAmnesia) and the wiki has a big page on the most common [hollywood amnesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrograde_amnesia) (treatment put repeated blunt force trauma as a non-option)

Comment: I am surprised to find this question has not been asked before.

Comment: I live with a brain tumor and have had 4 craniotomies and have the following relevant information to share. The brain is able to remap or restore memory by a term referred to as 'plasticity' in neuro science. This takes time. In my case I suffered peripheral vision loss after my first surgeries in 20210 and they came back. I also had memory issues that continue to improve. As my memory improves I often recall the most oddest things that I would never have imagined to come back to me.

Comment: Bart's advice to Homer before fighting a large man: "Make sure he hits you in the head an even number of times so you don't get amnesia!"

Answer (score 3):

Cecil Adams, the syndicated columnist of "The Straight Dope", addressed this precise issue in this column (which sides with "Woodchip", more or less), that a closed-head injury is rarely so black and white that the person loses all past memory only, then miraculously regains past memory with another head blow.

[Can you get amnesia from a blow to the head?](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2504/can-you-get-amnesia-from-a-blow-to-the-head)

Comment: This really needs something a bit more scientific and reputable than a random link on the internet.

Comment: Define "random", please?

Comment: Random meaning not a reputable source. And no, I would not consider "The straight dope" as a reputable source for medical issues. Please provide some link to peer-reviewed research.

Comment: @nico, since the OP's question specifically asks about the return of memory with a second blunt force impact, that would require citing reputable research or findings on that specific phenomena.  Exhaustive searching has not produced any examples.  Isn't absence of evidence, considered evidence to the contrary?

Comment: absolutely not. Absence of evidence is considered absence of evidence and it would be a very good answer.

Comment: Hold your horses, @nico, Cecil Adams *is* a reputable source.

Comment: @marton78: sure, so is Batman...